# Whats the best way to control voltage AC from 0 - 18VAC with a Arduino

Tags: arduino, voltage, ac

What would be a good method of controlling low AC voltage with an Arduino

I have an old motor (Lionel Postwar Train Motor from 1956 [example](https://ctt.trains.com/how-to/restoration-repair/2018/07/troubleshooting-vintage-o-gauge-locomotives)) that runs on AC between 5vac and 18vac with a max of 8amp

I need to be able to manipulate the voltage with the Arduino so I can gradually increase or decrease it. Preferably as a percentage (0% = 0vac > 100% = 18vac) or decimals

So just to clarify. The power coming to the Arduino is already transformed at a constant 18vac.

I just need to safely control the voltage

Thanks

Comment: I was born around then and my Lionel train set used a variac to control the voltage. An expensive but obvious solution would be to use a servo attached to a variac. But there is some discussion of a semiconductor approach [here](http://www.trainfacts.com/trainfacts/?paged=4). So you might read that over and see. (Do note that you really don't have lots of "practical speed steps" that are important, so you do not need smooth control. You can do this in steps, I think.)

Comment: Apart from @jonk sulution with morotized variac, a 2 ohm load capable amplifier which can supply 150 W into one channel fed via a 50/60 Hz souce you can control would do the job. How fast is the D/A output on your Arduino?

Comment: PWM variable duty cycle signal from Arduino controlling a bidirectional switch (FET in a bridge or other). As long as PWM frequency is >> AC frequency you get variable voltage AC.  Train motor will act as part of a filter. Flyback control on turn off may need a little thinking. || TRIAC phase control may work -  Ardiono controlled light dimmer - motor MAY not like part cycle AC. || BUT is it rectified to DC of one or other polarity before the train sees it - photos appear to show a DC train. That's MUCH easier to manage. Full V DC at PWM frequency can be better than smooth lower voltage DC.

Comment: Yes @RussellMcMahon a PWM is what im looking for, i was honestly hopping for a off the shelf module that might work but everything i found so far is for 50vac-220vac and nothing in the 0-18 range. I guess i will have to build my own

Comment: @IgorMatkovic Is the actual train fed with AC or rectified (possibly unfiltered) DC.? || There are numerous DC speed controllers avaiable via Ali Express or ebay that would meet a DC controller need.

Comment: It's AC 100% @RussellMcMahon . The train is being powered by a Lionel CW-80 Transformer (Output 18VAC/80W) I don't see anything inside the train to convert the AC > DC but i double checked now and its AC. Also if it were DC then it would be a lot easier to find a prebuilt module to accomplish this. All AC modules are rated way to high to even activate on low voltage like this. I started building my own version of a PWM

Comment: @IgorMatkovic A DC controller "inside" a bridge rectifier may work. Feed AC1 to load then load to bridge ACin and bridge ACout to AC2. If you short Bridge + -  outputs load runs on full AC. Now place a DC speed controller between bridge DC+ and DC-. Controller sees rectified full cycle DC but load sees AC. PWMing the DC load control (or using a variable resistor or electronically variable equivalent) will alter the AC.

Comment: All the pictures in your link show universal motors that will operate on AC or DC always in the same direction unless you swap the stator coil wires the other way with the reversing circuit.  There is no way to make a direction controllable AC brush motor of this type unless it is also a DC motor.

Comment: @KalleMP From the question his name desire is apparently speed control. He did not mention direction (I think). My recently added answer allows DC control of AC (hopefully)

Comment: @RussellMcMahon  With AC you cannot control direction by changing polarity,  it has to be done some other way. My point is that a universal brushed motor will work better with DC (except with perhaps __slightly__ elevated commutator and brush wear due to no 100/120 Hz current interruptions).

Comment: @KalleMP Yes - I understood your point, and I'm aware of universal motors. I asked whether the locomotive proper used AC or DC (maybe a Selenium rectifier in there somewhere) as it would be easier to vary DC than AC. | My answer addresses the fact that it's AC by using a bridge rectifier to provide the controller with full wave rectified DC and the load with AC. | Odds are converting the whole system to DC would work - unless there is some  clever tricks hidden there. eg point switching 'engines' rated for AC (higher inductance, resistance too low for undropped DC). Unlikely, but ... . .

Comment: @KalleMP The train has something called a E-Unit and is used to switch polarity and go into reverse (https://dfarq.homeip.net/how-does-a-lionel-e-unit-work/).  Converting everything to DC is a option but my goal here is to keep the old engine as is. Working on/expanding what Russell suggested. Will have more to update soon. Tnx

Comment: @IgorMatkovic The train may well work on full wave rectified unfiltered DC - adding a bridge rectifier to the AC feed will easily confirm this. This is because a universal motor has field & armature fed by the same voltage so that when the polarity reverse (with AC) both field & armature swap polarity so have the same results relative to each other. If you feed the motor full wave rectified DC it is liable to be "just as happy" as if the half cycles alternated in polarity. | The e unit works by changing the relative polarity of the field coil - this will still work with full wave rectified DC.

Comment: @IgorMatkovic  Right, Like Russel says it should work and easy to test with rectified AC.  Regulated DC may cause some additional commutator or E-unit arcing.  Both systems may allow for PWM or linear voltage regulation.  However it is important to note that the E-Unit will not work if the voltage is too low.  It will also miss-fire if the voltage drops low enough to release the solenoid and then increases enough to pick up again, the solenoid may be very sensitive and keep holding after power off if driven with DC so the opposite may also occur and it will not release reliably. YMMV

Comment: The beast you are looking for turns out to have a name.  It is a variable voltage inverter or drive.  Rarely found in small devices as easier methods are usually available.  https://www.ijsr.net/archive/v7i9/9091802.pdf

Comment: IF it was needed an electronic fixed frequency variable voltage AC source would be 'not too hard', but odds are the other easier suggestions to date will work.

Answer (score 1):

A DC controller "inside" a bridge rectifier may work.
Feed AC via load bridge ACin and bridge AC out to AC2.

If you short Bridge + & - outputs the load runs on full AC.

Now place a DC speed controller between bridge DC+ and DC-.
The controller (pot or PWM short or ...) sees rectified full cycle DC but load sees AC.

PWMing the DC load control (or using a variable resistor or electronically variable equivalent) will alter the AC

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqp56u.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

---

It's likely that converting the whole system to DC would work - unless there is some  clever tricks hidden in there. eg points switching 'engines' rated for AC (higher inductance, with resistance too low for undropped DC). Unlikely, but ...
. .